# Vetor em linguagem C, calcular a media dos alunos

Tags: c, array

Boa noite, estou estudando um código que foi feito no visualg e quero adaptar ele para o C. Quero que o usuário entre com 4 alunos e cada aluno tenha 2 notas para ser calculada na média e mostrar quais alunos estão acima da média.
Porem, o programa nao imprime os nomes e nem calcula certo a media.So imprime LISTAGEM DE ALUNOS .
Eu tentei arrumar mas não achei a solução em lugar algum. Código abaixo

Não consegui colocar a imagem da saída mas vou digitar abaixo um exemplo do que eu gostaria que fosse me apresentado na saida:

```
Listagem de alunos
------------------
Ana          5.0
Paula        9.5
Gustavo      2.5
Maria        5.0
Ao todo temos 2 alunos acima da média da turma que é 5.8
```

CÓDIGO ABAIXO:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

 int main ()
 {
   int i,total;
   char nome[4];
   float n1[4],n2[4],mediaaluno[4],somamedia,mediaturma;
   
    for ( i = 1; i <=4; i++)
    {
      printf("\nAluno %d:",i);
      scanf("%s", &nome[i]);

      printf("\nPrimeira nota:");
      scanf("%f", &n1[i]);

      printf("\nSegunda nota:");
      scanf("%f", &n2[i]);

      mediaaluno[i] = (n1[i] + n2[i])/ 2;

      somamedia = somamedia + mediaaluno[i];
    }

      mediaturma = somamedia/4;

       system("cls");
       printf("\nLISTAGEM DE ALUNOS\n");
       printf("--------------------------\n");

       for ( i = 1; i <=4; i++)
       {
        printf("\n%s %f",nome[i],mediaaluno[i]);
        if (mediaaluno[i] > mediaturma)
        {
         total++;
        }
       }
       
       printf("\nAo todo temos %d alunos acima da media da turma que e %.1f",total,mediaturma);

 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Exatamente qual é a pergunta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As strings em C são tratadas como vetores de caracteres, então pra usar elas da forma que deseja deverá usar matrizes, faça as alterações:

```
char nome[4][10];  //na declaração da variavel

scanf("%s", nome[i]); // na leitura da variavel
```

E ao acessar o vetor você deve lembrar que os índices dos elementos começam em 0, então o for vai acabar sendo da seguinte forma:

```
for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {}
```

faça essa alteração no código que deve funcionar como deseja.

Comment: Muito obrigada pela ajuda, funcionou perfeitamente!